# Why BinaryFormatter cannot deserialize his own result

Tags: c#, deserialization, wif, claims-based-identity, binaryformatter

I need help to figure out why BinaryFormatter cannot deserialize identity:

```
var identities = new[]
                     {
                         new ClaimsIdentity("Bug")
                             {
                                 Actor = new ClaimsIdentity("Bootstrap Context as a string")
                                         {
                                             BootstrapContext = "this causes issue"
                                         },

                                 BootstrapContext = new BootstrapContext("this raw token")
                             }
                     };

var sessionToken = new SessionSecurityToken(new ClaimsPrincipal(identities));
byte[] buffer;
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(ms, sessionToken);
    buffer = ms.ToArray();
}

using (var ms = new MemoryStream(buffer))
{
    var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    sessionToken = (SessionSecurityToken)formatter.Deserialize(ms);
}
```

This causes an exception TargetInvocationException with internal message:

"Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.BootstrapContext'."
I am not able to debug Framework to figure out it by myself, so I asks yours help to find out a root of this unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `BootstrapContext` property in the `ClaimsIdentity` is of the type `Object`. This means that you can assign a string to it (as you did). However, [reading the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsidentity.bootstrapcontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you can see that it should in fact be a [`BootstrapContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.bootstrapcontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object, which is probably expected during deserialization.

Comment: So, the property accepts System.Object but always should be an instance of BootstrapContext if we assume use serialization?

Comment: @DmitriySosunov Yes, that is how I interpret it. I would say that it should _always_ be a `BootstrapContext` instance, whether serialization is used or not.

Comment: Thanks, I have sent my comments to Vittori (author of System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt), I have found this issue when worked with ActAs scenario and JWT tokens, and there Vottiry saves a context as a string.